# Deploying two websites in my IIS and accessing using my machine name

Tags: asp.net, iis

I am trying to deploy my website in IIS ,I have already deployed one website using the binding of my machine name as host name and at port 80 ,is it possible to deploy another webpage using my machine name ,when I try to deploy another webpage and add same bindings it doesn't allow me saying only one can be used ,so how can I deploy multiple web pages ,I checked this article
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/28693/Deploying-ASP-NET-Websites-on-IIS-7-0#DeployonIIS7
but it provides details about hosting only one webpage, should I modify the hosts file or can someone point me to a article where multiple webpage are added. And I need to access this webpage from other machines as well ,can this be done?

Answer (score 1):

here is a nice article on doing it using different methods.[Link](http://weblogs.asp.net/istofix/archive/2009/08/18/hosting-multiple-websites-applications-on-iis-part-1.aspx) You might want to use Host Headers based on your requirements. Please provide more info.

Comment: thanks for the article I used different port numbers for my machine name as host and deployed the two sites and was able to access it from other machines as well.

Comment: glad that you got it working. i was recommending host headers because it gets messy when using port numbers. users need to know on which port the website is working and append the TCP port to the website address.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use the same host name in the bindings of 2 different websites in IIS on the same IP. You need separate host names. You can set multiple host names to point to the same IP address, either using your hosts file or setting it up in DNS. For example, in DNS or hosts if you have the following:

10.10.10.1   www.hostname1.com
10.10.10.1   www.hostname2.com

Then in your IIS server you can have both websites set up, one with a host name binding of www.hostname1.com and the other with a host name binding of www.hostname2.com. Both can use the same IP address and port number.

HTH,
-Brandon

Comment: Thanks for answering ,I got it deployed using different port number with my same machine name in the binding .I will try your solution of adding the host name in host file ,thanks